# How do I determine the power state of my monitor?

Tags: display, power-management

How do I determine the state of my Monitor in Ubuntu 11.04. I've seen a lot of stuff regarding dpms, but for what ever reason, I don't have the dpms module running on my ubuntu install and I'd really rather not go messing with my xorg.conf file if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are probably looking for xranr:

`xrandr -q`

will give you a list of connected monitors with spec info.

See http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2

Comment: I get this error: 
RandR extension missing

Comment: Nevermind. xrandr -q did it. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet--glad to hear you got it sorted.